# How to Display files from blob storage instead of downloading

Tags: azure, file, azure-blob-storage

Need to just display the files from Azure Blob Storage and not download the Files.

Don;t want to make in code changes for the viewing the files instead just need to make changes from Azure Portal.

Tried accessing the file using generating and using SAS token and Url but its getting download instead just need to view it.

Also not to change code from the Front End.

Comment: Please check the content type property of the blob. Make sure that it is set properly according to the file type (image/png for png images).

Comment: But where should I check this file type into type.
I'm using ReactJS as Front End where I consume the Blob Storage

Comment: You can check it in Azure portal. Content type property is set when a blob is uploaded but can be changed later.

Answer (score 1):

> Need to just display the files from Azure Blob Storage and not download the files.

I agree with Gaurav Mantri's comment, you need to check your **`content-type property`** in the Azure portal. If it is not the actual content-type, you can manually change it to the appropriate content-type.

Here is an example.

In my storage account, I have a file with the name **`sample.png`** with content-type **`application/octet-stream`**.

[image]

Now, if I paste the blob URL with SAS token, it will download.

**Browser:**

[image]

Now, I changed the appropriate content-type to **`image/png`** in the portal.

**Portal:**

[image]

Now, when I paste the blob URL with SAS token, it will display the image.

**Browser:**

[image]